# Batch Files Copy

Tags: batch-file, copy

I am trying to build a batch file (or any other that makes my life easier) to copy some files from one machine to some fixed set of machines.

For example:

files on Machine A
c:\folder\folder1\Folder2

Machines: B,C,D,E

I need to copy one file from Machine A - Folder1 into the respective folders on each machine(B,C,D...), the destinations are fixed, the only "moveable" part is the source which I need to be different everyday.

If the file exists on any of the folders, they should be replaced. Another detail is that all the files on these folders are the most recent ones, so if I could just call the script/file and it would copy the most recent files to the other machines would be great.

So I was hoping you guys could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//I;m not sure if this would help but, here goes nothing.

```
@echo off 
:: First create variables with all your machine path here
set A=Machine_A\Update_folder\*.*
set B=Machine_B\folder_1
set C=Machine_C\folder_1
set D=Machine_D\folder_1
::now the we'll read all the new file that has been exist on Machine A folder and copy to all other machines..
copy /y %A% %B%
copy /y %A% %C%
copy /y %A% %D%
echo.
echo Files from machine a has been Copy to all machines....
pause
```

Comment: that worked great, The only thing I'd like to know is: is it possible to only copy the most recent files on the folder? Because the command copies all files on that folder and they are quite a lot of files.

Comment: @Sleepgoing: see the "Related" questions on the right side of this page. It should get you on your way.

Comment: @Stephan: I did try it out, found one that helpe me out a bit but it won't work, what i got was this:
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
DIR /o-d /b D:\www\SpV\wwwroot\images\*.png > FileList.txt
set /A Counter=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (D:\www\SpV\wwwroot\temp\FileList.txt) do (
    set /A Counter+=0
    if !Counter! gtr 0 (
            if not exist machine2\www\SpV\wwwroot\%%a (
                    echo Copying D:\www\SpV\wwwroot\%%a to machine2\www\SpV\wwwroot\%%a
                    copy D:\www\SpV\wwwroot\%%a to machine2\www\SpV\wwwroot\%%a
    ) )
)
del FileList.txt

Comment: `set /a counter+=0` adds `0` to `counter`. For actual counting, add `1`. Your `copy`command has a ` to ` between source and destination (probably a "copy-and-paste"-problem)

Comment: without the "to", it works, been using it for a while now, I believe it may be the counter.